# MySql - Adding columns to select degrades performance

Tags: mysql, performance, select, indexing, using

I have a table with several million rows of data. I have a primary key on id, and a compound unique key on col2, col3, col4 and my_date (called comp_indx). Sample data is shown here...

```
id   col2 col3 col4 my_date             col5 col6 col7
1    1    1    1    2020-01-03 02:00:00 a    1    a
2    1    2    1    2020-01-03 01:00:00 b    2    1
3    1    3    1    2020-01-03 03:00:00 c    3    b
4    2    1    1    2020-02-03 01:00:00 d    4    2
5    2    2    1    2020-02-03 02:00:00 e    5    c
6    2    3    1    2020-02-03 03:00:00 f    6    3
7    3    1    1    2020-03-03 03:00:00 g    7    d
8    3    2    1    2020-03-03 02:00:00 h    8    4
9    3    3    1    2020-03-03 01:00:00 i    9    e
```

If I perform the following query...

```
SELECT col2, col3, max(my_date)
FROM table
where col4=1 and my_date <= '2001-01-27'
group by col2, col3
```

...the query is very efficient, and running the explain command shows...

```
select_type type  key       key_len rows Extra
----------- ----- --------- ------- ---- -------------------------------------
SIMPLE      range comp_indx 11      669  Using where; Using index for group-by
```

However, if I run a similar command (only requesting more columns - none of which are part of an index), e.g...

```
SELECT col2, col3, max(my_date), col5, col7
FROM table
where col4=1 and my_date <= '2001-01-27'
group by col2, col3
```

...then the performance drops right off, and if I run the explain command again, I get...

```
select_type type  key       key_len rows     Extra
----------- ----- --------- ------- -------  -----------
SIMPLE      index comp_indx 11      5004953  Using where
```

I can see that the type has changed from range to index, and I can see that the index is no longer being used for the group-by.

I am trying to understand why this is happening, and more importantly, how can I fix this issue?

BTW the table definition is...

```
CREATE TABLE `my_table` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `col2` smallint(6) NOT NULL,
  `col3` smallint(6) NOT NULL,
  `col4` smallint(6) NOT NULL,
  `my_date` datetime NOT NULL,
  `col5` char(1) NOT NULL,
  `col6` char(1) NOT NULL,
  `col7` char(1) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  UNIQUE KEY `comp_indx` (`col2`,`col3`,`col4`,`my_date`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB;
```

Comment: Can you edit your question and tag the DBMS, Can you also share your table definition ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have now fixed my performance issue by using 2 selects on the same table and a join, e.g...

```
SELECT *
FROM (
    SELECT col2, col3, max(my_date) as max_date
    FROM table
    where col4=1 and my_date <= '2001-01-27'
    group by col2, col3
) aaa
join
(
    SELECT col2, col3, my_date, col5, col6, col7
    FROM table
    where col4=1
) bbb
on (aaa.col2=bbb.col2 and aaa.col3=bbb.col3 and aaa.max_date=bbb.my_date);
```

Answer (score 1):

Add the following index

```
alter table my_table add key cl4_dt_cl2_cl3 (col4,my_date,col2,col3);
```

Moreover , the following query is invalid if sql_mode only_full_group_by is enabled

```
SELECT col2, col3, max(my_date), col5, col7
FROM table
where col4=1 and my_date <= '2001-01-27'
group by col2, col3
```

Comment: Thanks, I wasn't even aware of 'sql_mode only_full_group_by'. I'll take a look.

Answer (score 1):

Your original query:

```
SELECT col2, col3, max(my_date), col5, col7
FROM table
where col4=1 and my_date <= '2001-01-27'
group by col2, col3
```

col5, col7 should be added to the group by clause as well right?

Answer (score 1):

If you don't need `id` for anything, then this this will speed up the query, regardless of the extra columns (col5/6/7) that you need to fetch.

```
CREATE TABLE `my_table` (
  `col2` smallint(6) NOT NULL,
  `col3` smallint(6) NOT NULL,
  `col4` smallint(6) NOT NULL,
  `my_date` datetime NOT NULL,
  `col5` char(1) NOT NULL,
  `col6` char(1) NOT NULL,
  `col7` char(1) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (col4,my_date,col2,col3)  -- in this order
) ENGINE=InnoDB;
```

If you do need `id` because of it being referenced from other table(s), then add

```
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  INDEX(id)  -- This is sufficient to keep auto_inc happy
```

My suggested  PK is 11 bytes (vs 4-byte INT).  Any secondary will include those 11 bytes.  However, any columns that are common between the PK and the secondary index won't be repeated.  For example `INDEX(col2, col7)` will be effectively `INDEX(col2, col7, col4, my_date, col3)`.

Keep in mind that the PK determines the "locality of reference" of the rows.  Any secondary index starting with `col4` will be almost useless since the PK starts with that.  (This, of course, depends on cardinality, etc, etc.)

Comment: I was trying to keep the primary key as small as possible, as I may need to add extra indexes later. Also, do you know if there is a logical reason why the problem is happening, or is it just MySQL having a **best** guess?

Comment: @Wannabe-Coder - I added some discussion of that.  Would you care to say how many rows will be in the table?  And what semantics the columns have?  And other queries you might have?

Comment: Thanks for the extra clarification. There are currently 5M rows, but soon to be 25M rows, and then at some point, there will be a lot more (the figure I have been given could be 1B+!!). Not sure about the columns/queries yet as this is all still up in the air, and changing daily! So if I have this correct, are you saying that if I create another index that uses some columns that are already in the primary key,then the columns will be merged, as opposed to duplicated?

Comment: Actually, there will be several new string columns that will also need a compound index on them, if that helps?

Comment: I think "yes" is the answer to your comments.  Each index, including the PK, provides an efficient way to do certain queries.  I take each query, design an optimal index, eliminate duplicates, make compromises to avoid having too many.  It is normal for columns to show up in different positions.  I repeat, the PK is one of the indexes involved.

Comment: And there are times when an artificial id slows down some queries.  I can't tell whether this comment applies in your case.  25M rows, even with indexes, is only a few GB, not terribly big today.

Answer (score 0):

You probably need to add this covering index to make the second query faster :

```
create index comp2_index on my_table(col2, col3, col4, my_date, col5, col7);
```

Comment: The reason I didn't add a covering index is that there will be times when I want to select different combinations of extra columns, e.g. col5+col7, col6+col7, etc,. I was just surprised that it had an impact, and that is the part I am trying to understand.